# Point-free for filter function

Tags: haskell, filtering, pointfree, tacit-programming

Does there exist a point-free function for `filter` function to find minimum of first element of pair in a list? for example:

```
findMinimum xs =  filter ((== minimum (map fst xs)) . fst ) xs

-- example:
findMinimum [(0, 0), (0, 1), (2, 2), (3, 2), (1, 4)] = [(0, 0), (0, 1)]
```

How to convert `findMinimum` function to point-free:

```
findMinimum = ??
```

Comment: Every function can be written in point-free form; the question is, does the point-free form read better than a pointed equivalent?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

a different implementation

```
head . groupBy ((==) `on` fst) . sortOn fst
```

sort and group by first, pick the first sub list.  Perhaps you may want to handle empty list explicitly.

Comment: Of course, this replaces a pair of O(n) traversals with an O(n lg n) sort.

Comment: Great answer, thank you. I modify it a little bit for my need to handle empty list: `concat . take 1 . groupBy ((==) `on` fst) . sortOn fst`. It desired as accepted answer.

Comment: I don’t think it’s O(n log n) (using O informally).

Answer (score 6):

[pointfree.io](http://pointfree.io) outputs this, which is not too bad. I still prefer the original code, though.

```
findMinimum = filter =<< (. fst) . (==) . minimum . map fst
```

Comment: Yes, this is not too bad, I prefer point-free version and vote it up. Does exist more readable answer?

Comment: @JoeChoi I don't think there's anything much better since you have two occurrences of `xs`, so one needs something like `>>=` or `<*>` to "duplicate" the implicit argument. Using `<*>` seems to lead to worse code, IMO.

Comment: @JoeChoi maybe just use the optional parens, `filter =<< ((. fst) . (==) . minimum . map fst)`, to make the grouping more visually apparent.

Answer (score 2):

Putting the pair in [`Arg`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-Semigroup.html#t:Arg), you get ordering on the first element, that you can exploit as follows:

```
import Data.Semigroup (Arg(..))
import Data.Ord (comparing)

findMinimum :: Ord a => [(a, b)] -> (a, b)
findMinimum = minimumBy (comparing (uncurry Arg))
```

Comment: Thank you. I vote up for `comparing (uncurry Arg)` to provide another way to do that as `comparing fst`. But `findMinimum` return list of pair as `[(a,b)]` rather than `(a, b)`.